# AttributeError: Image has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, attributeerror

I'm new to learning the Tkinter Module that is built in Python. I was trying to build a simple Image Viewer GUI using pillow. I'm getting an Attribute Error here.

```
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkinter import *
base = Tk()
base.title("Image Viewer")
base.iconbitmap("download.ico")
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("download.png"))
label1 = Label(image = img1)
label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
base.mainloop()
```

I can't seem to find a fix for this and none of the solutions for similar questions on StackOverflow, work.

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 6.4.1. Importing * From a Package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
```

this imports everything from tkinter, including 
Image:

> ```
> Init signature: Image(imgtype, name=None, cnf={}, master=None, **kw)
> Docstring:      Base class for images.
> File:           [...]
> Type:           type
> Subclasses:     PhotoImage, BitmapImage
> ```

So, the Image module that you import earlier from PIL is overwritten.

you can

a) reverse the order:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

b) import only that what you need from tkinter

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import Tk
```

c) import Image as something else:

```
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image as PILImage
from tkinter import *
```

Comment: Can you tell me how the Image module of the `tkinter` package is different from the one in the `PIL`package ( as it seems from your answer that they are ' _this imports everything from tkinter, including Image_ ' )?

Comment: tkinter's Image is just a class, as I show in the quoted text. PIL's Image is a complete module that has many functions. So, they are completely different things that happen to have the same name.

Answer (score -1):

You can do onething try to use this snippet

```
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk
im = PIL.Image.open("download.png")
photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
```